# How can I create a custom function using a variable-sized array input?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am very new to advanced Excel use, so apologies in advance for anything I mis-identify.

In trying to automate some statistics gathering on a spreadsheet, I want to be able to define a custom function (either through a name definition or a VBA function) that can calculate a value with an array of indeterminate length.

Currently, the function I can copy-paste and change cell values is as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((I46:I58="D")*(L46:L58<>"Anonymous"))+
 SUMPRODUCT((I46:I58="Throwaway")*(L46:L58="Anonymous"))
```

Amending the array for every single use of the function is not optimal for the amount of data that I will be processing, and I'd like to find some way to have a name definition that automatically populates the arrays (perhaps by searching the I column for a specific value) or VBA function that populates the row numbers based on input cells.

I have tried a few different solutions based on searching for various functions, but I haven't been able to come up with a winning combination. Is there a better way to programatically populate the array values when the length is different for each function run?

Comment: Yes you can do this using VBA but you would need to explain exactly how the range would be determined.

Comment: Both the I and L rows contain a selection of words. The two ranges I would like to determine programatically would be I or L column, row of output to row of first instance of the word "Goal"

Comment: "Goal" is in which column?

Comment: In I column. The I column is actions and the L column is the actor, so I is the primary column to check, L is used for confirming if the action is applicable

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following. You added additional information which is incomplete for range determination. You can use `Range.Find` method to get the cell where `"Goal"` is found and take the row number of that cell to determine the row end of your range. What is unknown is which column that is in and also how you are determining the *"row of output"* for your range start.

With that information you would use that range address in the function below.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()   
    Debug.Print Foo(Range("L46:L58"))
    Debug.Print Foo(Range("L46:L90"))   
End Sub

Public Function Foo(ByVal rng As Range) As Double
    rng.Parent.Evaluate ("SUMPRODUCT((" & rng.Address & "=""D"")*(" & rng.Address & "<>""Anonymous""))+SUMPRODUCT((" & rng.Address & "=""Throwaway"")*(" & rng.Address & "=""Anonymous""))")
End Function
```

Comment: And how would you determine row of output?

Answer (score 0):

Still not really sure what you're looking for, but this would be my best guess:

```
Function Counts()

    Application.Volatile
    Const FORMULA As String = _
               "SUMPRODUCT(1*(I<r1>:I<r2>=""D""),1*(L<r1>:L<r2><>""Anonymous""))+" & _
               "SUMPRODUCT(1*(I<r1>:I<r2>=""Throwaway""),1*(L<r1>:L<r2>=""Anonymous""))"
    Dim clr As Range, f As Range, ws As Worksheet, rv, txt

    Set clr = Application.ThisCell '<< this is the cell holding the formula
    Set ws = clr.Parent            '<< the worksheet

    'find the first "Goal" in ColI
    Set f = ws.Range(ws.Cells(clr.Row, "I"), _
               ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Find(what:="Goal", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        txt = Replace(FORMULA, "<r1>", clr.Row)
        txt = Replace(txt, "<r2>", f.Row)
        'Debug.Print txt
        rv = ws.Evaluate(txt)
    Else
        rv = "No Goal!"
    End If

    Counts = rv

End Function
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Where the yellow-shaded cell has `=COUNTS()`